# Python json.dump() to javascript JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, python, json, twitter, d3.js

**Problem Summary**: can't parse through string that's formatted as a JSON object from .json file

**Long Version**:
I have some tweets I'm processing with Python where I create a json file I'm wanting to pass into d3.js and parse. I'm writing the tweets I get, into a file, so I have to serialize them with the `json.dump()` command in Python before I write them to a file.

Python

```
def on_data(self, data):
        f = open("tweets.json","a")
        tweet = json.loads(data)

        d = {
                "created": tweet["created_at"],
                "text": tweet["text"]
        }

        final_tweet = json.dumps(d)
        f.write(final_tweet)
        f.close()
        return True
```

However when I get the json file and try to grab it in my `d3.json("tweets.json")` it prints out the correct json format in the file:

```
{ 
  tweet:[
           {"key":"value"},
           {"key":"value"}
  ]
}
```

but I cannot parse the data with the code I'm using because `console.log(JSON.parse(data))` does not print out any object value.

```
d3.text("tweets.json", function(error, data){

  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  console.log("hello3");
  console.log(JSON.parse(data));
});
```

**EDIT** I edit the file that gets written to by manually adding braces at the top and bottom.

Comment: The JSON you listed isn't valid. The Object syntax – `{...}` – requires every value to have a corresponding key. There are 4 such values, but only 2 have keys. If the outermost layer is a list, the result should use the Array syntax – `[...]`.

Comment: the data is already a JSON so this will give you error `console.log(JSON.parse(data));` just do `console.log(data)`

Comment: The json you show us doesn't ever write to a file so it can't produce the output you show. And if it did, you open in append mode but you can just append serialized json strings to make a list. Regardless, json dumps don't look like the example you show. There is nothing here even remotely accurate... so how do we help?

Comment: @tdelaney I've added the necessary edits to make my question more transparent

Comment: I'm working on the theory that its not valid json in the file. For instance, your example is missing quotes on the key. if you are appending multiple json strings to build the list and manually making it a list at the end... each entry needs a comma at the end, whch you show in the example but don't do in the code.You could test the file in python with `json.load(open("tweets.json"))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Json instead and check your Json data [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

```
{ 
  "keys":[
    {"key":"value"},
    {"key":"value"}
  ]
}
```